# Putting a customer on hold when your phone lines are very busy

Tags: travail, téléphone

I would like to know the proper way to ask a customer if its alright to put them on hold while I search for the person or to hold until the person they want to speak to is not occupied.

Comment: Do you try to improve some first-hand version ? If so, maybe show us what you have for now, even if you're not so sure about it, it'll be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a simple:

"Un instant, s'il vous plaît"

is more than polite enough for your need.  For more politeness, you can state the reason *before* you use the previous form, for example:

"Je vais chercher M. Paradis pour vous, un instant s'il vous plaît"

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui suit me semblerait tout à fait approprié:
What follows would sound appropriate to me:

> Puis-je vous demander de patienter un instant ?

Ou encore:
This would also work:

> Puis-je vous faire patienter un instant ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pick up the phone, tell them quickly "don't hang up", and put them on hold (e.g. a receptionist handling several simultaneous brief incoming phone calls), I've heard people say something like,

> *Cabinet médical, ne quittez pas*. (or, possibly *ne raccrochez pas*)

If you want to ask them whether they're willing to wait quite a while, after you've talked to them and found out what they want, perhaps you'd say,

> *Voulez-vous attendre quelques instants?* (or) *Pouvez-vous attendre quelques minutes?*

Comment: "Voulez vous attendre" and "pouvez vous attendre" sounds weird to me. Using first person sounds more natural. "Puis-je vous faire patienter quelques minutes ?" (as Shlublu suggested)